# work requirement for Colombian people

Tags: ros, gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Job description:

Person is required to work on a robotic project.
Please find below a list of relevant qualifications:

-knowledge in the following programming languages: C++, python.
-knowledge in ROS concepts(nodes,topics,etc)
-knowledge in control system.

If you are interested and live in Colombia, please send your E-mail contact.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60956/work-requirement-for-colombian-people./) by [robot_colombia](https://answers.ros.org/users/4653/robot_colombia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm interested...

---

Originally posted by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) with karma: 756 on 2013-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on 2013-04-17**:
Yeah me too. Please give us your e-mail id.

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-04-17**:
Are you from robot_colombia or are you asking them for their e-mail too?

**Comment by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on 2013-04-17**:
I am not from robot_colombia. I am asking for their e-mail id.

**Comment by [robot_colombia](https://answers.ros.org/users/4653/robot_colombia/) on 2013-04-22**:
Nuestro mail es:
proyecto.robotica.colombia@gmail.com
Pueden enviar un mensaje indicando sus datos o una manera de contactarlos; para enviarles con mas detalle, la información sobre el proyecto en cuestión.